# Form valdiation with boolean multiplication not working

Tags: javascript

Please check this [code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLRKJ61OWYV3)

It's a form with 3 text inputs, 2 radio buttons and a select input.

I wrote a js function which displays an alert if all the three text inputs are not empty and the selected option is not the first option, otherwise the function displays nothing.

But instead it displays the alert if the text inputs are not empty regardless of the select input.

Comment: Multiplication happens first. `0 * anything = 0`

Comment: @PHPglue Can you please explain more.

Comment: Math happens before `<` and `>`, unless you use `()`. But if you're just testing to see if those values are not empty then you can just use `if(firstElement.value !== '' && secondElement.value !== '' && thirdElement.value !== '')`. Oh, I would separate your JavaScript from your HTML. I'll give an example soon.

Comment: @PHPglue Oh yes I see I added `()` and it works fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to multiply boolean values. You can just check against the .value property and user the or operator ||

```
if (!F.nom.value || !F.mail.value || !F.age.value || !F.prof.selectedIndex)
   alert('form has empty fields');
else 
   alert("ok")
```

In JavaScript anything that is an empty string, undefined, null or 0 evaluates to false so you can just check the value i.e.

```
if (formElement.value)
```

that will evaluate to true if the value is NOT an empty string, undefined, null or 0.

Comment: I know this can be done with various ways, I just want to know what I'm missing there.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you learn something from this:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, E, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
E('frm').onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}
var nom = E('nom'), mail = E('mail'), age = E('age'), m = E('m'), f = E('f');
var prof = E('prof'), out = E('out');
E('env').onclick = function(){
  if(age.value !== '' && mail.value !== '' && age.value !== '' && (m.checked || f.checked) && prof.value !== '0'){
    out.innerHTML = 'A very basic Client-side check for empty values was performed.';
  }
  else{
    out.innerHTML = 'The form was not completed.';
  }
}
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:936px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
table{
 width:300px;
}
thead th{
  font-size:24px;
}
tfoot{
  text-align:center;
}
tbody th{
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Exo 9</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form name='frm' id='frm'>
      <table>
        <thead><tr><th colspan='2'>Exo 9</th></tr></thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
              <input id='env' name='env' type='button' value='Envoyer' />
              <input id='reset' name='reset' type='reset' value='Annuler' />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Nom:</th>
            <td><input id='nom' name='nom' type='text' /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Email:</th>
              <td><input id='mail' name='mail' type='text'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Age:</th>
            <td><input id='age' name='age' type='text' /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Sexe:</th>
            <td>
              <input id='m' name='sexe' type='radio' value='m' /><label for='m'>M</label>
              <input id='f' name='sexe' type='radio' /><label for='f'>F</label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Profession:</th>
            <td>
              <select id='prof' name='prof'>
                <option value='0' disabled='disabled' selected='selected'> -- choisir un option -- </option>
                <option value='Médecin'>Médecin</option>
                <option value='Ingénieur'>Ingénieur</option>
                <option value='Professeur'>Professeur</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

External JavaScript and CSS are cached into the Browser's memory, for faster subsequent loads (until the Client clears their cache). Keep this in mind if you are changing the CSS JavaScript. You may have to clear your cache. On a live site you'll want to change the URL to one you know won't be cached.